# Extracting URL part (blog name) with Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am working with the following URL: http://www.espn.com/blog/stephania-bell/post/_/id/3563/key-fantasy-football-injury-updates-for-week-4-2

I am trying to extract the name of the blog as (stephania-bell).

I have implemented following function to extract the expected value from URL:

```
def getBlogName( def decodeUrl )
{
    def urlParams = this.paramsParser.parseURIToMap( URI.create( decodeUrl ) )
    def temp = decodeUrl.replace( "http://www.espn.com", "" )
            .replaceAll( "(/_/|\\?).*", "" )
            .replace( "/index", "" )
            .replace( "/insider", "" )
            .replace( "/post", "" )
            .replace( "/tag", "" )
            .replace( "/category", "" )
            .replace( "/", "" )
            .replace( "/blog/", "" )
    def blogName = temp.replace( "/", "" )
    return blogName
}
```

However I am missing something and the value it returns is `blogstephania-bell`. Could you please help me understanding what I am missing in the function implementation? Or maybe there is a better way of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of job can be easily handled by regular expression. If we want to extract URL part between `http://www.espn.com/blog/` and the next `/` then following code will do the trick:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

def url = 'http://www.espn.com/blog/stephania-bell/post/_/id/3563/key-fantasy-football-injury-updates-for-week-4-2'

def pattern = Pattern.compile('^https?://www\\.espn\\.com/blog/([^/]+)/.*$')

def (_, blog) = (url =~ pattern)[0]

assert blog == 'stephania-bell'
```

Comment: Adding a link to Groovy's [find operator `=~`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_find_operator) may help. Also the [multiple assignments](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-multiple-assignments.html) in `(_, blog) =` is a useful pattern - in combination with regex capture-groups. The `_` is a special variable often used for ignored values.

Answer (score 2):

It may be more useful to treat URL as is by Java's class `URL`. Then:

1. extract the *path* as String using [`getPath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getPath())
2. split into *segments* by path-delimiter [`split("/")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))
3. extract relevant path-segment using array-index `pathSegments[2]`

```
String plainText="http://www.espn.com/blog/stephania-bell/post/_/id/3563/key-fantasy-football-injury-updates-for-week-4-2";
    
def url = plainText.toURL();
def fullPath = url.getPath();
def pathSegments = fullPath.split("/")
assert "stephania-bell" == pathSegments[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not what you asked, but just for fun (I thought this is what you wanted at first)

```
@Grab('org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3')
import static org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect

def name = connect('http://www.espn.com/blog/stephania-bell/post/_/id/3563/key-fantasy-football-injury-updates-for-week-4-2')
  .get()
  .select('.sticky-header h1 a')
  .text()

assert name == 'Stephania Bell Blog'
```

Comment: That is a very neat way!